# Unable to wrap text in Kendo UI Angular grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a AngularJS Kendo UI data grid and there is a column which could have long string values. I want this column to wrap it's text.

Below is the column definition from my gridOptions in my controller:

```
{
    field: "ErrorMsg",
    title: "Error Msg",
    type: 'string',
    headerAttributes: 'style="overflow: visible; white-space:normal; text-align:center"',
    attritbutes: { style: "overflow: visible; white-space:normal; text-align:left; word-wrap:break-word;" }
}
```

I've explored some solutions provided on other forums but nothing worked so far.

**Update**: Attaching screenshot of the view.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share an example of output, either a screenshot or working code?

Comment: @Brett, I've updated the question with the screenshot of the view output.